# Is it possible to transit from Tel Aviv terminal T3 to T1 without passport control

Tags: transit, london, dubai, israel

I've a single entry Israel visa granted for 3 months. After spending 3 days in Israel, I have to travel to Dubai from Tel Aviv for 2-3 days and return back. The flight from Dubai to Tel Aviv lands in terminal T3. I have to come back to Tel Aviv ***only to*** board the flight back to London LTN from there - EasyJet airline departing from Ben Gurion airport T1. I don't plan to reenter the country.

Since the Israel visa granted is a single entry visa, will I be allowed to make the transit from T3 to T1 without it being considered as 2nd entry to the country?

Comment: What citizenship do you hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a new visa as you need to enter

Putting that you are an Indian citizen (any visa-required country will have the same message) in TIMATIC (database for document requirements):

> ### Israel - Transit Passport
>
> #### Admission and Transit Restrictions
>
> Passengers are not allowed to transit through Israel.

Comment: Yes, hold an indian passport. Thank you for your reply.